# Can an flex application be blocked with an adblock?

Tags: flash, apache-flex, flash-builder, adblock

Can it be blocked with an adblock like Adblock Plus or others...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It can be blocked the same way as a banner if it's URL matches the black list e.g. `http://domain.com/ads/...`.

Some versions of AdBlock allows to block Flash embeds from roll-over menu.

Some browsers, expecially mobile ones, can disable all Flash embeds until user manually clicks on particular embed to download and start it.